# select all checkbox in header , to select all checkboxes in that column

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsf-2.2

I have used the code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(window).load(function () {
    $(document).delegate(".checkall", "click", function(event) {
      $(this).closest("table").find(':checkbox').attr('checked', this.checked);
    });
  });
</script>
```

This code is working fine when I select/deselect the checkbox in header for the first time. But when I again select the checkbox then this code is not working. The checkboxes are not selected.

Comment: check this answer it will have everything you need:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/426258/setting-checked-for-a-checkbox-with-jquery  Also you will need to wrap it in if statement: if($(this).closest("table").find(':checkbox').attr('checked')){ /*check code*/ }else {/*uncheck code*/} And use .prop better

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `.prop()` instead of `.attr()`. And you have to check if an element is already checked.

```
...
  var $checkbox = $(this).closest("table").find(':checkbox');
  if ($checkbox.is(':checked')) $checkbox.prop('checked', false);
  else                          $checkbox.prop('checked', true);
...
```

Comment: I just replaced .attr with .prop in my mentioned above code. It is working fine.  But when I deselects one of the check boxes in the column below, then the header checkbox should also be deselected automatically. But it is not happening.

Comment: I'm afraid I can't help you with that problem until I see your `html`. Create a jsfiddle so I can take a look.

Comment: Iam unable to create jsfiddle .please suggest

Comment: I need to see your `html` to suggest anything. At this moment of time I can't suggest anything and can't see any reasons for desired behaviour of your script. Show me more code.